# css class not wroking when i add awesome font class to kotlin html tag first

Tags: html, css, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-html-builder

[image]

Hello guys
I appreciate you if you help me about this
in (i) kotlin.html tag when I add two class the first class is not working

```
div {

    css {
        width = 100.pct
        height = 500.px
        position = absolute
    }


  button{

        css {
            position = absolute
            top = 50.pct
            backgroundColor = NamedColor.white
            width = 50.px
            height = 50.px
            right = 0.px
        }

        **i{
            className = ClassName("fa fa-home")
            css {
                color = NamedColor.black
                width = Auto.auto
            }
        }**
    }
}
```

Comment: what's the purpose of the picture at top?